# input type with apex or quote PHP

Tags: php

I have this situation:

```
value='<?php echo $row["manometro_irroratrice"]; ?>'
```

My value `$row["manometro_irroratrice"]` contain word like `l'alba` or `"citazione"` i have a problem with the `value= --> '' <--- apex` there is a way to print words with `"` or `'` without problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usr `addslashes` to negate the effect of such quotes in your string as follows:

```
value='<?php echo addslashes($row["manometro_irroratrice"]); ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the escape character in PHP is the slash.

```
value='<?php echo \($row["manometro_irroratrice"]); ?>'
```

More info here http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php